# Как соединить две процедуры или переделать одну процедуру в функцию?

Tags: delphi, алгоритм, delphi-xe5

Подскажите, как соединить две процедуры или переделать одну процедуру в функцию так, чтобы из первой процедуры (функции) передать значение во вторую.

```
Function TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);

var

a , b : string;

i : integer;

begin

a := Edit1.Text;

b := Edit2.Text;

i := Pos (b, a);

ShowMessage(IntToStr(i));

end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);

var

a : string;

caunt : integer;

begin

a := Edit1.Text;

caunt := Length(a);

Delete (a, 5, caunt);

ShowMessage (a);

end;
```

Мне нужно переменную `i` из первой процедуры вставить во вторую процедуру `Delete (a, 5, caunt);` вместо `"5"`.

Скрин:

[image]

Comment: @Klonny изучите для начала теорию о процедурах и функциях. Это же основы языка.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Может, так:

```
Function MyFunc(a, b: string): integer;
Begin
  Result:= Pos(b, a);
End;
```

Тогда вызов будет таким:

```
...
Delete (a, MyFunc(Edit1.Text, Edit2.Text), caunt);
...
```

А если избавиться от вызова своей функции, то можно так:

```
...
Delete (a, Pos(Edit2.Text, Edit1.Text), caunt);
...
```

Answer (score -1):

Или просто сделать I глобальной переменной и спокойно использовать во второй процедуре без выкрутасов)